# Hosting applications written in Haskell: Heroku vs IaaS

Tags: haskell, heroku, hosting, paas, iaas

I'm considering the different options for hosting a web application written in Haskell.

Heroku seems like an attractive alternative, and it [supports Haskell](https://haskellonheroku.com/#haskell-on-heroku). However, as described in the [Heroku runtime principles](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles) it is quite likely that I will need to connect the web process with some background jobs (either via a message queue, or using platforms like Cloud Haskell). Also I will need a persistence layer, and I don't know how well this is supported in Heroku when using Haskell.

My question is then whether Heroku supports deploying a full blown Haskell application, or a [running containers on a IaaS](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2015/12/yesod-hosting-docker-kubernetes) (such as AWS or Google Computing Engine) is a better option.

Comment: Would it be possible to run your application on a docker container, as I understand it the environment you deploy to would be agnostic of the setting (if it was haskell or php or whatnot) as the container has all the information needed to run the application. (Note: devops/deployment are not my field of expertise - this is just a guess). And if I remember correctly [`stack`](https://haskellstack.org) is fully capable of working with docker containers

Comment: Yes, Running on Docker is possible indeed. However the downside of IaaS is the time spent on setup/maintenance. That's why a PaaS like Heroku is more attractive. However, I'm worried about the lack of flexibility in this platform. Hence my question :)

Comment: Check [this blog](https://www.kaashif.co.uk/2015/03/30/openshift-vs-heroku-haskell/). That's what I'm basing my opinion on.